# nestjs app can't connect to Postgresql Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs

```
I got the project, I try the game and it gives out:

ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
    error: ������������ "admin" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
        at Parser.parseErrorMessage (E:\Programming\Nodejs\LandPro\sportmaster\sportmaster_bitbucket\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
```

The project has a container defined in docker-compose.yml, but the application itself is local - not in docker

1. I run docker-compose up -d
   the container is created, I look at the necessary database is created
2. I launch the nest start application and the error is - it cannot connect to the database

   docker-compose.yml:

> ```
> version: '3.8'
>
> services:
>   db:
>     container_name: sportmaster
>     image: postgres:14.4
>     restart: always
>     environment:
>       - POSTGRES_USER=${TYPEORM_USERNAME}
>       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${TYPEORM_PASSWORD}
>       - POSTGRES_DB=${TYPEORM_DATABASE}
>     volumes:
>       - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
>     ports:
>       - ${TYPEORM_PORT}:${TYPEORM_PORT}
> ```

.env:

```
TYPEORM_USERNAME=admin
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=admin
TYPEORM_DATABASE=sportmasterDB
TYPEORM_PORT=5432
```

typeOrm config:

```
const ormconfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  logging: false,
  entities: [
    Order,
  ],
  synchronize: true,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
};

export default ormconfig;
```

docker-compose ps:

### Name                  Command              State           Ports

sportmaster   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem recently. In my case it was caused by `postgres service` running on Windows and listening to the same port. Apparently, I installed it some time ago and completely forgot. I'm almost sure you have the same problem. Just try to stop the `postgres service`.

In order to stop Windows service press `Win+R`, then type `services.msc`, hit enter, find posgress service, stop it. You can also change it's startup type to `manual` to prevent it from starting at boot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You saved me, how did you figure out this answer?

Comment: Hi @Simon, I'm so glad I've saved you some time. I remember it took me several days trying to find some usefull information. Eventually I started to dig into localization issues since error message contains wrongly decoded characters. Then out of nowhere this idea pops up in my mind - maybe I have another running instance of Postgres DB on my machine 

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide "host" in your database settings.

Try this:

```html
const ormconfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: db,
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  port: 5432,
  logging: false,
  entities: [
    Order,
  ],
  synchronize: true,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
};

export default ormconfig;
```

The host is a docker-compose database service name.

You can add this variable in your ".env" file.

.env:

```html
TYPEORM_HOST=db
TYPEORM_USERNAME=admin
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=admin
TYPEORM_DATABASE=sportmasterDB
TYPEORM_PORT=5432
```

typeOrm config:

```html
const ormconfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  port: 5432,
  logging: false,
  entities: [
    Order,
  ],
  synchronize: true,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
};

export default ormconfig;
```

Comment: I tried:
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  host: 'localhost',
  host: 'db',
no result

Comment: If your NestJS project are not in docker-compose file, you can't use db service name in host. I think "127.0.0.1" is a correct value for host in your case.
Try to check if you get correctly environment variable in your typeOrm config. If environment variables are undefined, try to implement a module provide by nest to manage environment variables https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Comment: I tried to write all the settings for the database in typeorm directly in lines without using variables

Comment: I tried to connect to the database from the VSCode plugin, the result is the same

Comment: Can you try this commands to check if you can connect to the database ?
In terminal : 
`docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`
`psql -U admin`
`\c sportmasterDB`

Comment: this command doesn't work, rel bush , but the following works
`"docker exec -it  sportmaster sh"`

`"psql --username=admin --dbname=sportmasterDB"` View: `sportmasterDB=# `